# Directory quota. Remote setting. C#

Tags: c#, .net, ntfs

I have task to manage quotas on remote server folders.
I have solved this task using COM library **srmlib.dll** for manage local folders quotas, thanks to [Jóhannes H. Laxdal](http://www.laxdal.org/node/27) for great post, but it can't help me to manage on remote server.

I found good solution for remote management: using [dirquota](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742027.aspx) - it works, but it doesn't fit me. I'm restricted not to use command line tools (long story).

Does anybody know any others solutions except command line tools **dirquota** ?